# How do I create a model from a state dict?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am trying to load a checkpoint pth file from the faster_rcnn_resnet101 model which is not currently in the PyTorch model zoo.
This causes PyTorch to throw a KeyError saying that I the layers in the state dict does not match the model architecture of faster_rcnn_fpn_resnet50 that I've loaded from the model zoo.

Note: I tried posting the architecture of the faster_rcnn_fpn_resnet50 model, but I went over the character limit of 30.000

print(state_dict[model].keys()):

```
backbone.stem.conv1.weight
backbone.stem.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.stem.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.stem.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.stem.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.0.shortcut.weight
backbone.res2.0.shortcut.norm.weight
backbone.res2.0.shortcut.norm.bias
backbone.res2.0.shortcut.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.0.shortcut.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.0.conv1.weight
backbone.res2.0.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res2.0.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res2.0.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.0.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.0.conv2.weight
backbone.res2.0.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res2.0.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res2.0.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.0.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.0.conv3.weight
backbone.res2.0.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res2.0.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res2.0.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.0.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.1.conv1.weight
backbone.res2.1.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res2.1.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res2.1.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.1.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.1.conv2.weight
backbone.res2.1.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res2.1.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res2.1.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.1.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.1.conv3.weight
backbone.res2.1.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res2.1.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res2.1.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.1.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.2.conv1.weight
backbone.res2.2.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res2.2.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res2.2.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.2.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.2.conv2.weight
backbone.res2.2.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res2.2.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res2.2.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.2.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res2.2.conv3.weight
backbone.res2.2.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res2.2.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res2.2.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res2.2.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.0.shortcut.weight
backbone.res3.0.shortcut.norm.weight
backbone.res3.0.shortcut.norm.bias
backbone.res3.0.shortcut.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.0.shortcut.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.0.conv1.weight
backbone.res3.0.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res3.0.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res3.0.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.0.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.0.conv2.weight
backbone.res3.0.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res3.0.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res3.0.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.0.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.0.conv3.weight
backbone.res3.0.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res3.0.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res3.0.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.0.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.1.conv1.weight
backbone.res3.1.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res3.1.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res3.1.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.1.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.1.conv2.weight
backbone.res3.1.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res3.1.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res3.1.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.1.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.1.conv3.weight
backbone.res3.1.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res3.1.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res3.1.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.1.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.2.conv1.weight
backbone.res3.2.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res3.2.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res3.2.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.2.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.2.conv2.weight
backbone.res3.2.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res3.2.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res3.2.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.2.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.2.conv3.weight
backbone.res3.2.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res3.2.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res3.2.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.2.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.3.conv1.weight
backbone.res3.3.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res3.3.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res3.3.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.3.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.3.conv2.weight
backbone.res3.3.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res3.3.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res3.3.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.3.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res3.3.conv3.weight
backbone.res3.3.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res3.3.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res3.3.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res3.3.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.0.shortcut.weight
backbone.res4.0.shortcut.norm.weight
backbone.res4.0.shortcut.norm.bias
backbone.res4.0.shortcut.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.0.shortcut.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.0.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.0.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.0.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.0.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.0.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.0.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.0.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.0.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.0.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.0.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.0.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.0.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.0.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.0.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.0.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.1.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.1.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.1.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.1.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.1.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.1.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.1.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.1.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.1.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.1.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.1.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.1.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.1.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.1.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.1.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.2.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.2.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.2.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.2.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.2.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.2.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.2.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.2.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.2.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.2.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.2.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.2.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.2.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.2.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.2.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.3.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.3.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.3.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.3.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.3.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.3.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.3.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.3.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.3.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.3.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.3.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.3.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.3.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.3.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.3.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.4.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.4.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.4.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.4.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.4.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.4.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.4.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.4.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.4.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.4.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.4.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.4.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.4.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.4.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.4.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.5.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.5.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.5.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.5.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.5.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.5.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.5.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.5.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.5.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.5.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.5.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.5.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.5.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.5.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.5.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.6.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.6.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.6.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.6.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.6.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.6.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.6.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.6.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.6.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.6.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.6.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.6.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.6.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.6.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.6.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.7.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.7.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.7.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.7.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.7.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.7.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.7.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.7.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.7.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.7.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.7.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.7.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.7.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.7.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.7.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.8.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.8.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.8.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.8.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.8.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.8.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.8.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.8.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.8.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.8.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.8.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.8.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.8.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.8.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.8.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.9.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.9.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.9.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.9.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.9.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.9.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.9.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.9.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.9.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.9.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.9.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.9.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.9.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.9.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.9.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.10.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.10.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.10.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.10.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.10.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.10.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.10.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.10.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.10.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.10.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.10.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.10.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.10.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.10.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.10.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.11.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.11.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.11.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.11.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.11.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.11.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.11.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.11.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.11.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.11.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.11.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.11.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.11.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.11.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.11.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.12.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.12.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.12.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.12.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.12.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.12.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.12.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.12.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.12.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.12.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.12.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.12.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.12.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.12.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.12.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.13.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.13.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.13.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.13.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.13.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.13.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.13.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.13.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.13.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.13.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.13.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.13.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.13.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.13.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.13.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.14.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.14.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.14.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.14.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.14.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.14.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.14.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.14.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.14.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.14.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.14.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.14.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.14.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.14.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.14.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.15.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.15.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.15.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.15.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.15.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.15.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.15.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.15.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.15.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.15.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.15.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.15.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.15.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.15.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.15.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.16.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.16.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.16.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.16.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.16.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.16.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.16.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.16.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.16.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.16.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.16.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.16.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.16.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.16.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.16.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.17.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.17.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.17.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.17.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.17.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.17.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.17.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.17.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.17.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.17.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.17.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.17.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.17.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.17.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.17.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.18.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.18.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.18.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.18.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.18.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.18.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.18.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.18.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.18.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.18.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.18.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.18.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.18.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.18.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.18.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.19.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.19.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.19.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.19.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.19.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.19.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.19.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.19.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.19.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.19.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.19.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.19.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.19.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.19.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.19.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.20.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.20.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.20.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.20.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.20.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.20.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.20.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.20.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.20.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.20.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.20.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.20.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.20.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.20.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.20.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.21.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.21.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.21.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.21.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.21.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.21.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.21.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.21.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.21.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.21.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.21.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.21.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.21.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.21.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.21.conv3.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.22.conv1.weight
backbone.res4.22.conv1.norm.weight
backbone.res4.22.conv1.norm.bias
backbone.res4.22.conv1.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.22.conv1.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.22.conv2.weight
backbone.res4.22.conv2.norm.weight
backbone.res4.22.conv2.norm.bias
backbone.res4.22.conv2.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.22.conv2.norm.running_var
backbone.res4.22.conv3.weight
backbone.res4.22.conv3.norm.weight
backbone.res4.22.conv3.norm.bias
backbone.res4.22.conv3.norm.running_mean
backbone.res4.22.conv3.norm.running_var
proposal_generator.rpn_head.conv.weight
proposal_generator.rpn_head.conv.bias
proposal_generator.rpn_head.objectness_logits.weight
proposal_generator.rpn_head.objectness_logits.bias
proposal_generator.rpn_head.anchor_deltas.weight
proposal_generator.rpn_head.anchor_deltas.bias
roi_heads.res5.0.shortcut.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.shortcut.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.shortcut.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.0.shortcut.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.0.shortcut.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.0.conv1.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.conv1.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.conv1.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.0.conv1.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.0.conv1.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.0.conv2.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.conv2.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.conv2.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.0.conv2.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.0.conv2.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.0.conv3.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.conv3.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.0.conv3.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.0.conv3.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.0.conv3.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.1.conv1.weight
roi_heads.res5.1.conv1.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.1.conv1.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.1.conv1.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.1.conv1.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.1.conv2.weight
roi_heads.res5.1.conv2.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.1.conv2.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.1.conv2.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.1.conv2.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.1.conv3.weight
roi_heads.res5.1.conv3.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.1.conv3.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.1.conv3.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.1.conv3.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.2.conv1.weight
roi_heads.res5.2.conv1.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.2.conv1.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.2.conv1.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.2.conv1.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.2.conv2.weight
roi_heads.res5.2.conv2.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.2.conv2.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.2.conv2.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.2.conv2.norm.running_var
roi_heads.res5.2.conv3.weight
roi_heads.res5.2.conv3.norm.weight
roi_heads.res5.2.conv3.norm.bias
roi_heads.res5.2.conv3.norm.running_mean
roi_heads.res5.2.conv3.norm.running_var
roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.weight
roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.bias
roi_heads.box_predictor.bbox_pred.weight
roi_heads.box_predictor.bbox_pred.bias
```

Is there a way to dynamically create the model architecture of the faster_rcnn_resnet101 model in torch by iterating over the model dict or is there another way?

I have tried searching for a GitHub repository with a hubconf.py for torch.hub, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR; the short answer is you can't.**

The [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) of a [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html) contains the module's state, but not its function. It is not possible to instantiate a model with its state dictionary alone.

You can manage to initialize some of the sub-modules based on the state *dict* keys and the weight shapes, but this is not guaranteed. In any case you won't be able to *know* the model's behaviour because this information is simply not contained in its state dictionary. Therefore you are required to have access to the `forward` definition of the model in order to know the forward logic, *i.e.* which functions are applied on the input and intermediate outputs and in which order those submodules are used.

---

Have a look at this minimal example showing two models with identical state dictionaries. However, their `forward` is different from one another:

```
class A(nn.Linear):
    def forward(self, x):
        return super().forward(x)

class B(nn.Linear):
    def forward(self, x):
        return super().forward(x)**2
```

Here, `a` and `b` are initialized and the state *dict* is copied from one to the other:

```
>>> a = A(2,1)
>>> b = B(2,1)
>>> a.load_state_dict(b.state_dict())
```

Both `a` and `b` have the exact same state... but actually implement two different functions!

Comment: Well, that blows... Thanks for the great explanation